# calling asp webservice not working as i need

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to send user and pass to asp webservice , but when getting back response get like this :

so how to fix it and get true of false

this is webservice link i have used :

```
http://ictfox.com/demo/Hafil_Updates/Login_Check.aspx?UserLogin=Demo&Password=Demo 


02-20 19:57:23.326: D/Http Response:(4007): True<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title></head><body>    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Login_Check.aspx?UserLogin=Demo&amp;Password=Demo" id="form1"><input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZD/N053U40olll80mNvY/Qt2aBEc" />    <div>        </div>    </form></body></html>
```

this is my full class in asyncTask android :

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Creating HTTP Post
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "http://ictfox.com/demo/Hafil_Updates/Login_Check.aspx?UserLogin=Demo&Password=Demo");

    // Building post parameters
    // key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserLogin", "Demo"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",
            "Demo"));

    // Url Encoding the POST parameters
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        response.getEntity().getContentLength(); 


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = 
                   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        Log.d("Http Response:", sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that webservice from you or a 3dr party? It seems that it not only returns the actual return value, but also some hidden HTML stuff. Check if there is an option to call the service in a way that it returns only the desired value or even better JSON. If not, just check if the return String starts with "True"

```
boolean success = sb.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("true");
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the response sent by the server, that would be the easiest thing to do. I see that you server returns `True` followed by some HTML code. Make your server remove the HTML

If you don't want to modify the server side code, just look in your response for the substring `True`.

Additionally, to get the response I use this, which may be simpler:

```
httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
response = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
```

Comment: why it allows return true ? i have put invalid data but return true

Comment: It it always returns true, the problem is in the server, not the app.